# "Assign to contact" in UIActivityViewController not working...!

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios8.1

I need to do update image of a contact through `UIActivityViewContrller` But when activity menu comes then  it directly navigate to contact detail screen, it doesn't give option to update the image.
That's how I have implemented:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPic.png"];
self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

any idea..?

Comment: You can not pass an image in the `initWithActivityItems:` it only takes object that confirm to [`UIActivityItemSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource)

Comment: Can u please explain or give a references...!

Comment: The link to the App documentation is in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this excellent link from NSHipster.

http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

This gives you deep dive into UIActivityViewController.